# When I trigger a screenshot programatically, the Camera Preview disappears on the saved screenshot

Tags: android, android-camera2

I made an application which inspects if something build correct or false by image classification. After it has been classified it triggers a screenshot. All the UI elements are on the screenshot, but the actual image I need is left out.

When I do a screenshot manually nothing is left out.

So how can I change the code to make my application do a normal screenshot?

**My Launch Activity:**

```
/** Main {@code Activity} class for the Camera app. */
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    }

    public void startCamera(View view){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspection);
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container2, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
    }

}
```

**Inspection Activity:**

```
public class Inspection extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspection);
}

}
```

And the **takeScreenshot**() method which is used in the **Camera2BasicFragment** class:

```
    private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
      // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
      String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

      // create bitmap screen capture
      View v1 = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
      v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
      v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

      File imageFile = new File(mPath);

      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
      int quality = 100;
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();

      //openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to take a screenshot of the whatever the view you want,

```
private void captureScreen() {
  View v =  this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
  Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
  String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File file = new File(extr, "fff" + ".jpg");
  FileOutputStream f = null;
      try {
      f = new FileOutputStream(file);
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, f);
      f.flush();
      f.close();
      MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Screen", "screen");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used it with 
View v =  getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
and deleted
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Screen", "screen");
and got the same result...